# Python + expect + keepass(kpcli)

Tags: python

Есть на баше скрипт, который создает файл с паролями keepass

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://10.8.0.1"
pass_kp="$USER_KEE_PASS"
pass_vpn="$USER_PASS"
pass_z="$Z_PASS"
pass_tcp="$USER_TCP_PASS"
user_none="$USER"
#export PATH_KEE=$USER."kdbx"
echo $PATH_KEE
expect <<EOF
spawn /usr/bin/kpcli
send "rmdir eMail\n"
send "rmdir Internet\n"
send "mkdir clickme\n"
send "cd clickme\n"
send new\n
expect Title:
send vpn\n
expect Username:
send none\n
send "$pass_vpn\n"
send "$pass_vpn\n"
expect URL:
send \n
send \n

send new\n
expect Title:
send z\n
expect Username:
send $USER\n
expect Password:
send "$Z_PASS\n"
expect "Retype to verify:"
send "$Z_PASS\n"
expect URL:
send \n
send \n

send new\n
expect Title:
send secr_razd\n
expect Username:
send none\n
expect Password:
send "$USER_TCP_PASS\n"
expect "Retype to verify:"
send "$USER_TCP_PASS\n"
expect URL:
send \n
send \n

send new\n
expect Title:
send translations\n
expect Username:
send $USER\n
expect Password:
send "$USER:$USER_ICE_PASS\n"
expect "Retype to verify:"
send "$USER:$USER_ICE_PASS\n"
expect URL:
send \n
send \n

send "saveas /path/kee/$PATH_KEE\n"
send "$pass_kp\n"
send "$pass_kp\n"
send quit\n
expect
EOF
```

Который нормально создает файл file.kdbx

Решил перепиать его на Питоне

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
import os,sys
import pexpect

url='https://10.8.0.1'
path='/home/firefedot/'
pass_kp='cjcfnm'
pass_v='cjcfn'
pass_z='cjcfnm'
pass_tcp='cjcfnm'
user="userus1"
k=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/kpcli')
k.sendline("rmdir eMail")
k.sendline ('rmdir Internet')
k.sendline ('mkdir clickme')
k.sendline ('cd clickme')
k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('v')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline ('none')
k.sendline (pass_v)
k.sendline (pass_v)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline ('\n')
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('z')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline (user)
k.expect ('Password:')
k.sendline (pass_z)
k.expect ('Retype to verify:')
k.sendline (pass_z)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline (url)
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('secr')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline ('none')
k.expect ('Password:')
k.sendline (pass_tcp)
k.expect ('Retype to verify:')
k.sendline (pass_tcp)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline ('\n')
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('saveas '+path+user+'.kdbx')
k.sendline (pass_kp)
k.sendline (pass_kp)
k.sendline ('quit')
#k.interact()

os.chdir(path)
print(os.getcwd())
print (os.system('ls | grep user'))
```

Скрипт запускается, немного думает и выдает

```
/home/firefedot    - print(os.getcwd())
256                - print (os.system('ls | grep user'))
```

То есть файл не создается, но чтото делает. проверил на Fedora 22, CentOS7, питона 2 и 3. одинаковый результат.

Думал, может прав скрипту не хватает, хоть и домашняя директория, но не помогло. Запускаю pdb он проходит по всем строчкам и тоже не показывает ничего.

Получается, что он проделывает все операции, а сохранить не может.

Где и как можно поправить?

Comment: не хватает `k.expect(pexpect.EOF)` как в bash-cкрипте -- намерение: дождаться пока `kpcli` завершит свою работу (возможно стоит ещё         `k.close()` добавить на статус `k.exitstatus` посмотреть). Также (для отладки) `k.logfile = sys.stderr` можно установить.

Comment: Спасибо. k.close() решил проблему, файл создается и в нем есть все проли. что передаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой код дождется закрытия kpcli  и в итоге cаздаст файл.

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
import os,sys
import pexpect

url='https://10.8.0.1'
path='/home/firefedot/'
pass_kp='cjcfnm'
pass_v='cjcfn'
pass_z='cjcfnm'
pass_tcp='cjcfnm'
user="userus1"
k=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/kpcli')
k.sendline("rmdir eMail")
k.sendline ('rmdir Internet')
k.sendline ('mkdir clickme')
k.sendline ('cd clickme')
k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('v')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline ('none')
k.sendline (pass_v)
k.sendline (pass_v)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline ('\n')
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('z')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline (user)
k.expect ('Password:')
k.sendline (pass_z)
k.expect ('Retype to verify:')
k.sendline (pass_z)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline (url)
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('new')
k.expect ('Title:')
k.sendline ('secr')
k.expect ('Username:')
k.sendline ('none')
k.expect ('Password:')
k.sendline (pass_tcp)
k.expect ('Retype to verify:')
k.sendline (pass_tcp)
k.expect ('URL:')
k.sendline ('\n')
k.sendline ('\n')

k.sendline ('saveas '+path+user+'.kdbx')
k.sendline (pass_kp)
k.sendline (pass_kp)
time.sleep(0.6)
k.sendline ('quit')
k.close()  # Вот эта строчка решила проблему
```

Спасибо за подсказку.